# mosfet as a switch on arduino pin and xbee explorer board 5v

Tags: arduino, mosfet, xbee

I have looked at various examples of MOSFET switches but I am not knowledgeable enough to adapt what I see to what I would like....
I want to have a pin on my 5 volt Arduino Micro board turn on or off power to the Sparkfun Xbee Explorer Regulated Board. 
I don't think I can connect it directly to the Arduino pins because with the Xbee hooked-up and transmitting I think I will exceed the allowed current (20mA) on the Arduino pins. All I read about MOSFETs is using low voltage to control 12v or more... is it possible to use it to just turn the explorer board on or off as required ??  I would have a button press wake up my arduino board and then code to take the controlling pin to high (or low) as required to turn on the explorer board via MOSFET.

Thanks

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=logic+level+MOSFET

Comment: What is the supply voltage of the Xbee that you have to switch on or off?

Comment: Is it this? https://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/sfe-xbee-explorer-regulated.html

Comment: yes. gpio to gate, gnd to source, switched device - to drain, psu - to source. done.

Comment: Reinderien - yes that is it. I am supplying it 5v, the regulator takes care of taking it down to 3.3v along with the in & out pins. I am using Xbee S2C Pro which seem to draw 120mA when transmitting a signal, hence my concern about plugging it directly to an arduino pin.

Comment: @dandavis, Not sure I follow - too much of a newbie. How do i post an image of my schematic ? I wanted to use pin D19 on the Micro. So if I understand what you are saying D19 to Gate, GND to Source, Xbee Board  +5v to Drain.... PSU to Source - doesn't that cause a short with GND to Source ??

Comment: Xbee Board ground to Drain: you turn the ground on and off.